# htaccess don't log access to any file in dir except index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have 2 files in a dir that I do not want added to the access log.
They both have a diffrent get parameterson each request.

So:
    Request 1: file.txt?347547
    Request 2: file.txt?758453
    Request 3: file.txt?787646

How would I do this with htaccess?

I've tried:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/file1\.txt$" dontlog
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/file2\.txt$" dontlog
CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!dontlog
```

But it doesn't work because of the get parameters.

Comment: And what exactly is `dontlog`? It will just be an environment variable to apache. You still need to customise the log module.

Comment: I'm really bad with htaccess. I found that on another stackoverflow question.

Comment: But i dindn't include this in the question sorry:
i had CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!dontlog
 below it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't use `$` placeholder in your pattern.
2. You haven't mentioned it, so I will mention that you need to modify your [`CustomLog`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) directive.

Put this in your virtual host specifications:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/(file1|file2)\.txt" dontlog
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log common env=!dontlog
```

Comment: @user3349060 `common` is a name I use on my log formatter. You can specify your own. Also, where are you putting the above code?

Comment: I am putting it in the .htacces in the dir. But after some more Googling it seems I must put it in the site config?

Comment: @user3349060 You can put `SetEnvIf` statements in htaccess files, but `CustomLog` [context](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) states that it can be used only in server config or virtual host files.

Comment: Ok ive added the custom log into the site config. Now can you explain the "common" thing to me? Is it needed?

Comment: `common` is defined by [`LogFormat`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) directive.

Comment: And are you sure this will work no matter the get parameters?

Comment: It would have worked with your previous pattern too. On reading more into `SetEnvIf`, I notice that `Request_URI` is defined to be _portion of the URL following the scheme and host portion without the query string_.

Comment: Ok it is no longer added it to the log but is adding env=!dontlog. Anyway to not do that?